# How to Explicitly Specify File Directory in Python Script

Tags: python, windows, file, file-io, path

I'm trying to make my Python scripts run directly by typing the filenames into the run dialog on Windows, but I haven't been able to do it effectively. I have two simple scripts that I created after reading the Automate book on Python: one, a clipboard that's supposed to take command line arguments and another, a script that's supposed to generate text files. I have modified the environment variables to accommodate the path to these files and have even added a shebang line to them. I also tried to create a batch file for each of the files. Yet, when I try to run any of them, especially the text-generating script which is not a .pyw file using the run dialog, it shows the command prompt very briefly but doesn't actually generate the files. The script runs quite well when I double click it, run it from the command line or from the Python shell. How do I get around this?

This is the code for the text-generating script if it could be of use:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import random

   # The quiz data. Keys are states and values are their capitals.

capitals = {'Alabama': 'Montgomery', 'Alaska': 'Juneau', 'Arizona': 'Phoenix',
'Arkansas': 'Little Rock', 'California': 'Sacramento', 'Colorado': 'Denver',
'Connecticut': 'Hartford', 'Delaware': 'Dover', 'Florida': 'Tallahassee',
'Georgia': 'Atlanta', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu', 'Idaho': 'Boise', 'Illinois':
'Springfield', 'Indiana': 'Indianapolis', 'Iowa': 'Des Moines', 'Kansas':
'Topeka', 'Kentucky': 'Frankfort', 'Louisiana': 'Baton Rouge', 'Maine':
'Augusta', 'Maryland': 'Annapolis', 'Massachusetts': 'Boston', 'Michigan':
'Lansing', 'Minnesota': 'Saint Paul', 'Mississippi': 'Jackson', 'Missouri':
'Jefferson City', 'Montana': 'Helena', 'Nebraska': 'Lincoln', 'Nevada':
'Carson City', 'New Hampshire': 'Concord', 'New Jersey': 'Trenton',
'New Mexico': 'Santa Fe', 'New York': 'Albany', 'North Carolina': 'Raleigh',
'North Dakota': 'Bismarck', 'Ohio': 'Columbus', 'Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City',
'Oregon': 'Salem', 'Pennsylvania': 'Harrisburg', 'Rhode Island': 'Providence',
'South Carolina': 'Columbia', 'South Dakota': 'Pierre', 'Tennessee':
'Nashville', 'Texas': 'Austin', 'Utah': 'Salt Lake City', 'Vermont':
'Montpelier', 'Virginia': 'Richmond', 'Washington': 'Olympia',
'West Virginia': 'Charleston', 'Wisconsin': 'Madison', 'Wyoming': 'Cheyenne'}

for quiz_num in range(35):
    quiz_file = open('quiz_questions %s.txt' % (quiz_num+1), 'w')
    quiz_answers = open('quiz_answers %s.txt' % (quiz_num+1), 'w')
quiz_file.write('Name:\nMatric no:\nDate: \n \n')
quiz_file.write(' '*40 + "Ajanlekoko Nursery and Primary School \n \n")

states = list(capitals.keys())
random.shuffle(states)

for qst_num in range (50):
    right_answer = capitals[states[qst_num]]
    wrong_answers = list(capitals.values())
    del wrong_answers[wrong_answers.index(right_answer)]
    wrong_answers = random.sample(wrong_answers, 3)
    options = wrong_answers + [right_answer]
    random.shuffle(options)

    quiz_file.write('%s. What is the capital of %s?' % (qst_num+1, states[qst_num]))

    for i in range(4):
        quiz_file.write('\n \n  %s. %s \n' % ('ABCD'[i], options[i]) )
    quiz_file.write('\n')

    quiz_answers.write('%s. %s \n' % (qst_num+1, 'ABCD'[options.index(right_answer)]) )

quiz_file.close()
quiz_answers.close()
```

Comment: If you're finding the script by searching `PATH` instead of using an absolute path to run it, then Explorer probably sets the working directory to either the user's profile directory or `%SystemRoot%\System32`. I just checked in Windows 10, and it was the user profile directory, but I wouldn't depend on that. Check `print(os.getcwd()); input()`.

Comment: BTW, do you have an indent typo in the question, or does your code have a bug in the `range(35)` loop?

Comment: If you want files created relative to the script directory, use `script_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`. If you want them relative to the user's profile, use `home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')`.

Comment: Thanks, eryksun. I can see now that it is not that the script is not running, but that the files are being created under the user's profile directory as you mentioned. How do I get it to create the files in the script's own directory? I do not understand what I am supposed to do with script_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) (pardon my naivety; I'm new to this). Where do I put it if it is the solution to the problem I am facing? Thanks again for offering to help. :)

Comment: Just use a fully qualified path instead of using a relative path. For example: `quiz_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, 'quiz_questions %02d.txt' % (quiz_num + 1))`. Saving files to the script directory is OK for personal use when you know you have write access to the script directory, but in general non-admin users may lack write access, such as a script located in a "Program Files" subdirectory. You can default to the current directory, if that's preferred for interactive command line use, but provide a command line option to explicitly set the output directory.

Comment: Thanks, eryksun. I found a solution and I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around, I found this to be the simplest answer to my question:

```
import random
import os
import sys

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
```

This changes the working directory to the first command line argument (the script's name) when the script is run.

Comment: `script_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))` works, and will continue to work even if you freeze the script as an executable using py2exe. But I don't encourage the habit of changing the working directory. It's not thread safe once you start writing multithreaded code with multiple writers, potentially to different directories. Also, in Windows it means the final absolute path is limited to `MAX_PATH` (260) characters; the ``\\?\`` prefix that expands this to 32768 characters only works with fully qualified paths.